# Equivalence Relations and Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, cardinals, equivalence-relations

I'm looking at the question below from a past paper:

What is an equivalence relation? Say that two sets $X$ and $Y$ are related via the relation $\rho$ if $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality. Prove that $\rho$ is an equivalence relation.

Now, I know an equivalence relation is a relation that is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, but I thought they could only be defined between the same set? For example a relation $R \subset N \times N$ between $N$ and $N$. In this case you can define properties like reflexivity, but between two different sets surely you can't have the reflexive property? I assume $\rho$ is meant to represent the bijection between the two sets, in which case transitivity would be impossible as each member can only relate to one other member of the opposite set?

Comment: The set of all sets does not exist, but the class of all sets does. Maybe you can a define equivalence relation in a class?

Comment: No, $\rho$  does not represent a bijection between the two sets. $\rho$ is a relation between sets, defined so that $\rho(X,Y)$ is true if and only if there exists a bijection $f:X\to Y$.

Comment: Ooooooh. I'm misunderstanding the question then. I was thinking relation between the members of the sets, not the sets themselves.